# How to export Pyserial reading data into text file or Matlab

Tags: matlab, pyserial

I'm new to Pyserial, I am currently using it to read a bunch of data from microcontroller, the data format is like (1,2,3,4,....), and I want to save these data either into a text file or Matlab, how should I implement this? Thanks!

Comment: you should post the code that you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, here is a link to a repository I've been creating summarizing different methods of doing exactly that:

https://github.com/gskielian/Arduino-DataLogging/blob/master/PySerial/README.md

## Description below

---

## PySerial

Pyserial is an excellent way to grab data from your Arduino, and it is both robust and easy to implement.

The following examples shows a really simple approach for doing this, which will get you started.

**HOWEVER, be careful that the arduino is not constantly sending data to your program -- you will likely encounter errors from the buffer overfilling.**

#### Naive Pyserial and Sketch

#try this out first to get a feel for pyserial

**naive.py**

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)

f = open('dataFile.txt','a')

while 1 :
    f.write(ser.readline())
    f.close()
    f = open('dataFile.txt','a')
```

**naive.ino**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
  delay(1000);
}
```

#### Robust Pyserial and Sketch

When you're ready, consider having the arduino only send data when prompted by your python program:

**8robust.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',  115200, timeout = 0.1)

#if you only want to send data to arduino (i.e. a signal to move a servo)
def send( theinput ):
  ser.write( theinput )
  while True:
    try:
      time.sleep(0.01)
      break
    except:
      pass
  time.sleep(0.1)

#if you would like to tell the arduino that you would like to receive data from the arduino
def send_and_receive( theinput ):
  ser.write( theinput )
  while True:
    try:
      time.sleep(0.01)
      state = ser.readline()
      print state
      return state
    except:
      pass
  time.sleep(0.1)

f = open('dataFile.txt','a')

while 1 :
    arduino_sensor = send_and_receive('1')
    f.write(arduino_sensor)
    f.close()
    f = open('dataFile.txt','a')
```

**robust.ino**

```
void setup () {   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);   Serial.begin(115200); } 
    void loop() {

  if (Serial.available())    {

     ch = Serial.read();

     if ( ch == '1' ) { 
       Serial.println(analogRead(A0)); // if '1' is received, then send back analog read A0
     } 
     else if (ch == '2') {    
       digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // if '2' is received, turn on the led attached to 13
     } 
     else if (ch == '3') {
       digitalWrite(13,LOW); // if '3' is received then turn off the led attached 13
     } else {
       delay(10);
     }
   }    
}
```